# UITableView with a UITextField as a Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm using a UITableViewController, and with 2 sections. 
One section does use a Header and the other one doesn't.

The header view of one section, has an UITextField, an UIButton and an UISegmentedControl, all with AutoLayout using PureLayout Framework. 
When I scroll, the Header view stays fixed in the top (just as a normal header would do).
Now, When I click on the Button, I call a method to update an User, (taking the text from the UITextField) and as soon as I get the data, I reload the data from the table.
It is here, when the UIView used as a Header, jumps to the top of the screen, or if it's fixed on the top, disappears until I move the table the Header appears correctly.

Don't know what really it's happening, any ideas guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in **viewDidLoad**: `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` 
I have issue when in header was an image, and when i scroll header remain, but table content goes under it. I solve this issue with change style from **Plain** to **Grouped**. But i think this is does't help you, but maybe...Also check your creating tableView cells, if it they're custom - register nib of cell in **viewDidLoad**.